# Adding a tag for grammatical vocabulary?

Tags: discussion, tags

In [What is a 修飾語? Is it a modifier?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65415/what-is-a-%e4%bf%ae%e9%a3%be%e8%aa%9e-is-it-a-modifier) there is a question about what a Japanese grammatical word means. I could find no tag for this -- something like [grammatical-terms]. It cannot be so rare to bump into such technical words and wonder what they mean (in the sense of what grammar they pertain to, rather than translating them).

A few more questions looking like good candidates for such a label: [Is there an easily accessible list of terms in the Japanese grammar written both in Japanese and English?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9),  [What is a grammatical terminology to describe the group of the refrain of two syllable words like pera-pera, don-don, iki-iki?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30335)

Comment: [modification](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modification) っていうタグならあるんですが・・

Comment: およ・・じゃ、 [terminology](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) っていうタグならありますが・・